# What is the meaning of grep with stdout redirection to /dev/null in job script?

Tags: bash, grep

I have a bash script that is submitted as a bash job. It creates some files, executes some computations, moves the output files somewhere else and cleans up. For moving the output files, it contains these lines:

```
set -e
mv $tmp/stdout.txt $current/tmp.stdout.txt
grep Report $current/tmp.stdout.txt >/dev/null 2>&1
mv $current/tmp.stdout.txt $current/stdout.txt
set +e
```

If the computation was successfull, the output file `stdout.txt` contains several lines that start with `Report`; but none if not. Further processing checks that the `$current/stdout.txt` file exists (and resubmits the job otherwise).

The first `mv` moves the output file from the temporary directory to the final directory under a temporary name; and the second `mv` renames the output file to its final name. But what is the purpose of the `grep` in between? If the output file contains lines with `Report`, they are redirected to `\dev\null` and nothing happens. If the output file contains no lines with `Report`, it doesn't output anything, neither to the redirected `stdout` nor to the redirected `stderr`. So my impression is that this line does nothing and I should replace `mv`+`grep`+`mv` by a single `mv`. Which functionality do I overlook here?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The `set -e` is important here.

- `grep` sets its exit status to 0 the input file is successfully processed and any results are found, and a nonzero value otherwise.
- `set -e` tells the shell to exit if any checked command has a nonzero exit status. (It has a bunch of gotchas and caveats, and generally shouldn't be used; see [BashFAQ #105](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/105)).

Thus -- unless this code is embedded in a context that triggers one of the several scenarios where `set -e` has no effect -- your script terminates before the second `mv` if the `grep` has no matches.

---

A better way to write this section of your script would be:

```
mv "$tmp/stdout.txt" "$current/tmp.stdout.txt" || exit
grep -q Report "$current/tmp.stdout.txt" || exit
mv "$current/tmp.stdout.txt" "$current/stdout.txt" || exit
```

- `grep -q` is more efficient than `grep >/dev/null`, since it can exit immediately when a match is seen, whereas otherwise `grep` needs to read all the way to the end of the input file. (`2>/dev/null` is just generally bad practice, since it hides errors you'd need to know about to debug misbehavior; hence that being removed here).
- Quotes make variables with whitespace or glob characters safe, which they wouldn't be otherwise.
- Putting `|| exit` on individual commands you want to be fatal on errors is considerably more reliable than depending on `set -e` for the reasons given in [BashFAQ #105](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/105) (skip the allegory for the exercises below if in a hurry, or see https://www.in-ulm.de/~mascheck/various/set-e/ for a list of cases where `set -e`'s behavior is known to differ across different shells and/or shell releases).

Answer (score 2):

Grep will return an error code if no matches are found.

`set -e` means the error will stop the script.

There are other options on grep that will mean it has no output instead of doing all the capturing.

Answer (score 1):

The `set -e` configures the `bash` to abort at the first error it encounters.  If the `grep` fails (finds nothing), the `bash` will terminate after the `grep`.

Most `grep` versions, however, know the `-q` option which makes them quiet (suppress all output), so the redirection is not needed anymore.  Also, code relying on `set -e` isn't easy to maintain.  A proper `grep ... || exit 1` would be more explicit.

Comment: Just `|| exit` will do unless you want to force the exact value of 1. The default exit status for `exit` is `$?`, so if `... || exit` triggers an exit, `$?` is necessarily nonzero.